# Dask Kubernetes Operator can't reach apis/external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1

Tags: kubernetes, dask-kubernetes, kubernetes-metrics

My Dask Kubernetes Operator fails to start, because of this error:

```
[2022-12-04 12:17:28,456] kopf._core.reactor.o [ERROR   ] Request attempt #9/9 failed; escalating: GET https://10.64.0.1:443/apis/external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1 -> APIServerError(None, None)
```

When I use this command:

```
kubectl get --raw /apis/custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1
```

I get:

```
{"kind":"APIResourceList","apiVersion":"v1","groupVersion":"custom.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1","resources":[]}
```

But when I run this:

```
kubectl get --raw /apis/external.metrics.k8s.io/v1beta1
```

I get:

```
Error from server (ServiceUnavailable): the server is currently unable to handle the request
```

Any help would be very appreciated!

Comment: Is this related? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63526333/external-metrics-k8s-io-is-not-available-in-eks-cluster